# Merge single column of first record with respective to duplicate record in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this data in sqlserver

```
ID Phone 
1   100
1   200
2   300
2   300
3   400
3   500
3   600
```

I want output like this

```
ID Phone 
1   100,200
1   200 
2   300
2   300
3   400,500,600
3   500
3   600
```

Comment: What's the expected result if you add 1,100 and 3,500 to your table?

Comment: I didnt get ..? I want to keep data as it is in table , only need to update or add new column with the expected output . means duplicate should not be added.

Comment: I think he just wants the table as it is, but in the first occurrence of each `ID`, select all the different `Phone` values for that `ID`

Comment: yes , need to merge all unique phone no. into a single column for a perticular key

Comment: But the rule depends on how you treat the rows I suggested you to add!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
;with cte
as
(select id,phone,
stuff((select  distinct','+cast(phone as varchar(20))
from #valuee t2 where t1.id=t2.id
for xml path('')),1,1,'') as nwphone
from #valuee t1
)
select id,
case when 1=dense_rank() over (partition by id,nwphone order by phone) 
then cast(nwphone as varchar(20)) else cast(phone as varchar(20)) end as phone
from
cte
```

**Output:**

```
id  phone
1   100,200
1   200
2   300
2   300
3   400,500,600
3   500
3   600
```